# how can I set a picture into my Github profile for better display?

Tags: github

I need to add some logo and icon into my profile for look likes better

used the issues section to take my image link but it doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question isn't very clear. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the "[Changing your profile picture](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/customizing-your-profile/personalizing-your-profile)" and update your avatar:

[image: https://docs.github.com/assets/cb-126896/mw-1000/images/help/profile/edit-profile-photo.webp]

But that does not include an icon or logo, only a gravatar picture.

And you can also [beautify your GitHub profile page](https://github.com/rzashakeri/beautify-github-profile) to add much more details.
(This is done in the special repository `https://github.com/username/username`, the [README profile](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/customizing-your-profile/managing-your-profile-readme))

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rzashakeri/beautifygithubprofile/master/cover-repo.jpg]

*Then* your profile "home page" would look better.